# How to parent a cloth to a rigged mesh?

Tags: animation, mesh, modifiers, cloth-simulation, path

So, this is my setup:

[image]

I have parented a plane with the cloth modifier onto the mesh. However, when I play the animation, the cloth falls downwards, while the mesh continues on the path animation.
I want the cloth to follow the bird exactly like an advertising banner -- without  the mid air fluttering -- attached to an airplane.

PS : any other modifier-related help also welcomed.

Comment: In your case, I would just use a curve modifier. This doesn't answer your question, but it does get the result your looking for. I'll explain if your interested.

Comment: @cmomoney yes, please do :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't answer your question exactly, but it might produce the result your looking for.

First un-parent the banner. Then clear the location(<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd>). Add a Curve modifier and add your path as the curve object with Y as the deform axis. If the rotation is now wrong, rotate on the Y axis 90 degrees. Make sure your at the first frame of the animation, and move the banner on the Y axis until it is positioned behind the bird. Set a location keyframe(<kbd>I</kbd>, then "Location"). Go to the end of the animation and move the banner on the Y axis until it is again positioned behind the bird(type 302 into Y location it will get you close). Set another location keyframe. Go to the Graph Editor and under Key->Interpolation Mode choose "Linear".

So its not using a cloth simulation, but it should do what you want.

Comment: Interesting, I'll try that now

Comment: You certainly know the magic here! Thanks a ton, saved me a lot of rendering & baking time! :)

Comment: Mate, does the mess need to have a moderate to high poly count for this to work?

Comment: It only needs enough that it looks smooth(with smooth shading applied). It needs the geometry to bend right.